# Object.map lambda code is working in Chrome, Firefox, but not IE?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble getting this section of my code to work in IE.

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but IE throws a "critical error" on the lambda expression. So the page breaks in IE, but it works for other browsers.

The intent of the code is to filter out the javascript timestamp before loading them into editable fields on the page. It also only selects the data needed from each object, instead of loading all of the data. And I'm just not sure what the problem is in IE and how to fix it.

```
ContractsService.getRefRFRInformation()
.then(function (results) {
    var rfrInfo = results.data.map(x => ({ 
      rfrInformationID: x.rfrInformationID,
      fiscalYear: x.fiscalYear,
      rfrNumber: x.rfrNumber,
      startDate: ($filter('date')(new Date(x.startDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy')),
      endDate: x.endDate ? ($filter('date')(new Date(x.endDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy')) : "",
      modificationDate: x.modificationDate, modifiedBy: x.modifiedBy
    }))
    $scope.refRFRInfo = rfrInfo;
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using ?

Comment: Transpile (or refactor) it to ES5 code. Version of IE doesn't support arrow functions and probably not a lot of other ES6 features either

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, you are right. It's just an error with IE not supporting ES6.

Comment: See https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdas or arrow functions are part of the ES6 specification and are not supported by Internet Explorer. This is mentioned in  [this MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility). You need to change your code and pass the function in the old way.

```
results.data.map(function(x) { ... });
```

For more details, you can check what are the features which got introduced as part of ES6 in [this link](http://es6-features.org). Those will not be supported  by Internet Explorer or other older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking in [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions), they have support tables for most JS features and what share of browsers actually support them. As you can see, lambda functions don't seem to be supported at all in IE, so either go back to ES5 or use babel to get your code to be automatically transpiled.